# JSON serialization of generics

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, json.net

I have a class that looked like this:

```
public class MyData : IList<Tuple<double,double>>
```

The idea being that you have a list of pairs of values. Simple enough. But I wanted this to be serialized such that it looks like an array of an array of doubles (i.e. `double[][]`) rather than a list of tuples. It should look like this when serialized:

```
[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
```

So I created a simple `JsonConverter` that will do it. It has a very simple `WriteJson` method that looks like this:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var obj = value as MyData;
    double[][] dataArray = (from dp in obj._data
                            select new[] { dp.Item1, dp.Item2 }).ToArray();
    var ser = new JsonSerializer();
    ser.Serialize(writer, dataArray);
}
```

And I decorate `MyData` with the appropriate attribute:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDataJsonConverter))]
    public class MyData: IList<Tuple<double,double>>
```

And everything works fine. Now however, I want to extend this and make `MyData` generic:

```
    public class MyData<S,T>: IList<Tuple<S,T>>
```

And this is were I run into problems. Initially, I tried making `MyDataJsonConverter` also generic:

```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDataJsonConverter<S,T>))]
   public class MyData<S,T>: IList<Tuple<S,T>>
```

But that isn't allowed because you can't use generics with attributes.

So I have to keep `MyDataJsonConverter` non-generic, but I need to figure out how to flatten my collection of tuples into an array (presumably of `object[][]` now) such that when I serialize my data would look like:

```
[[1,2],[2,3]]
```

or:

```
[["foo":1],["bar":2]]
```

or even:

```
[["foo":"bar"],["what":"ever"]]
```

Any ideas on how to handle it? In `WriteJson`, I can no longer cast `value` to `MyData` because I won't know the type parameters, so everything just pretty much falls apart at that point.

I could just create separate classes for each type combination (so one for `Tuple<double,double>` and one for `Tuple<string,double>` and so on...), but I was wondering  if there was a better way before I go brute force on it.

Comment: Why `in obj._data` and not `in obj`? What is `_data`? In the second case you can just cast to `IEnumerable<object>` and use LINQ anyway.

Comment: @BartoszKP: or even call the nongeneric `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla To use LINQ you'd still have to convert it to `IEnumerable<object>` afterwards.

Comment: @BartoszKP: `obj._data` is the private `List<Tuple<double,double>>` that my class wraps. It's the part I actually want to serialize. I probably could just as easily have done `in obj`.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Actually, thinking about this some more, I need to be able to access the `Item1` and `Item2` properties of the tuple, so I tried casting to `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of `IEnumerable<object>` and that seems to work, at least while still only using `<double,double>` as my type. I'll have to check it with other types later. For reference, my `CanConvert` is slightly more complicated, but I can check type there by checking `objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyData<,>)` and that seems to work.

Comment: One other marginally annoying problem with this is that previously, I had my serializer as a nested class within the class that it supposed to serializer. This way, I could make it private and there was no chance of it being used elsewhere. Well, if the wrapping class is generic, apparently and nested classes are automatically consider generic too, even if they don't have any generic type parameters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so here's basically what I ended up doing (in case anybody else needs something similar). My collection looks something like this:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDataJsonConverter))]
    public class MyData<S,T> : IList<Tuple<S,T>>
    {
        private List<Tuple<S, T>> _data;
        // all the implementation of IList...
    }
```

And my custom converter (now no longer nested inside `MyData`) looks like this:

```
internal class MyDataJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyData<,>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Note: this is strictly for serializing, deserializing is a whole other
        // ball of wax that I don't currently need!
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = value as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
        object[][] dataArray = (from dp in obj
                                select new object[] { dp.Item1, dp.Item2 }).ToArray();
        var ser = new JsonSerializer();
        ser.Serialize(writer, dataArray);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to use `in obj`, not to couple yourself to the private members of the class, but to the interface it exposes. Then the only problem you have is to serialize `Tuple<S, T>` held through an `object` reference with unknown `S` and `T`. You can do it as follows, for example:

```
public static Tuple<object, object> UnpackUnknownTuple(object tuple)
{
    var item1Property = tuple.GetType().GetProperty("Item1");
    var item2Property = tuple.GetType().GetProperty("Item2");

    return Tuple.Create(
        item1Property.GetValue(tuple, null), 
        item2Property.GetValue(tuple, null));
}

public override void WriteJson(
    JsonWriter writer,
    object value,
    JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var obj = value as IEnumerable;

    var tuples = obj.Cast<object>().Select(UnpackUnknownTuple);

    object[][] dataArray = (from dp in tuples 
                            select new[] { dp.Item1, dp.Item2 }).ToArray();

    var ser = new JsonSerializer();
    ser.Serialize(writer, dataArray);
}
```

Another possibility is to convert to `string` instead of `object` but I guess it can interfere with some serialization settings. `item1Property` and `item2Property` can possibly be cached using first element of the list if there should be any performance problems.