# Generic Tree to JSON

Tags: c#, json, generics, tree, json.net

I have a generic tree structure representing employees in an organization chart.

The tree consists of a graph of custom `Node<Person>` objects which have references to each other and other properties like Level showing their level in the tree, parent, sibilings, etc.

I have to serialize a portion of this organization chart from a specific Person on down through everyone below them, and I have a method on the Node object called `SelfAndDescendants()` that returns an `IEnumerable<Node<Person>>`.

So basically I locate the specific person's `Node` in the tree, then get them and all their descendants in an `IEnumerable`.  This part works fine.

That's where I am stuck.  I now need to get this `IEnumerable` set of `Nodes` into hierarchical JSON.

My first attempt was just to throw it straight at the JSON serializer but that does not work (nor did I really expect it to), because it's a set of generic `Node` objects.  There is a `Value` property on the `Node` object that will return a `Person` object ... which is what I need to get into the JSON (just the name).

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personNode.SelfAndDescendants.ToList());
```

This obviously is trying to serialize a `List<Node<Person>>` at this point which is not what I need.  All the JSON return needs is a hierarchical format with simple the `Person` object's `Name`.  Nothing else.

Do I have to do anything manually here in a loop to build custom JSON and return that?

This is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294697/json-serialization-of-generics), as I am dealing with a generic recursive tree here and not a simple generic data structure.

Do I have to implement a custom `JsonConverter`?  How does this work with a series of `Node` objects in a tree?

The Node class has all sorts of properties but it basically looks like this:

```
public class Node<T> : IEqualityComparer, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<Node<T>> {

        public Node(T value) {
            Value = value;
        }

        public Node<T> this[int index] {
            get {
                return _children[index];
            }
        }

        public Node<T> Add(T value, int index = -1) {
            var childNode = new Node<T>(value);
            Add(childNode, index);
            return childNode;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Node<T>> SelfAndDescendants {
            get {
                return this.ToIEnumarable().Concat(Children.SelectMany(c => c.SelfAndDescendants));
            }
        }

}
```

The Person class is just a POCO class representing a person.  This class is already serializing out to JSON correctly for another part of the system.

```
    [JsonObject]
    public class Person {

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public List<StreetAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

        ... etc

}
```

The desired output is an organization chart, showing people's levels in JSON.  So employee under their boss, that boss under their boss, etc etc.

The JSON is extremely simple in this regard, it's just the persons name and title.  It can even just be a single string per employee.

Comment: Is `Node` serializable? If so, it sounds like the original `Node` object would have the structure you want. `SelfAndDescendants` sounds like it flattens the structure. It would be helpful if you provide code for `Node` and `Person` as well as the desired JSON structure for others to help.

Comment: @Layoric I have updated my question to include more information about the Node and Person classes.  Any help would be appreciated.  I don't know how to handle this complex Node class when the JSON just needs a bunch of people's names in a hierarchical structure.  I considered creating a much more simple class and then moving over all the data so that it can serialize, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have control over the `Node` class?

Comment: @GerardSexton Yes, I can modify as necessary.

Comment: Does this one help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294912/serializing-a-tree-into-json-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, given your constraints, I would say that creating a custom `JsonConverter` is an appropriate solution for this situation.  It is actually pretty straightforward to write, so long as `Node<T>` has public properties to allow at least read access to the `Value` and the `Children`.  You don't have to worry about looping; the serializer will call back into the converter for each child as it iterates over the `Children` collection via the `JArray.FromObject` call.

Here's how I would write it:

```
public class OrgChartConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Node<Person>));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Node<Person> node = (Node<Person>)value;
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        obj.Add("Name", node.Value.Name);
        obj.Add("Subordinates", JArray.FromObject(node.Children, serializer));
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, use the converter like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new OrgChartConverter() },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootNode, settings);
```

Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BfdFdW

Comment: Fantastic.   This is just what I needed and thank you for the code samples.  I was able to quickly get them into place and the JSON, while not perfect, I can handle the minor details.

Comment: This is being returned as XML for some reason ... any idea why that would be?  "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.." ... I use return `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json)` .. the method return type is `HttpResponseMessage` and when i look at the json variable in the debugger with the JSON visualizer it looks correct.  Fiddler is also able to parse the response into a valid JSON tree.  But it begins in the browser (Chrome) with `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">`

Comment: Oh, you are using Web API?  In that case, when you create the response, make sure you are putting the JSON into a `StringContent` object like this:  `HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`  That will keep Web API from trying to double-serialize it (either to XML or JSON).

Comment: Yes, Web API.   I rewrote it as you said and it is returning JSON content now.  Thanks.

Comment: Could adapt this code to my own tree without hassle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to describe how this class should be serialized by adding serialization attributes on the class and on the members needed and then serialize to string

```
string nodes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Node<Person>>(personNode);

[JsonObject]
public class Node<T> : IEqualityComparer, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<Node<T>> {

    [JsonProperty]
    public IEnumerable<Node<T>> Children { get { return _children; } }

    ...

}
```

[JSON.NET Serialization Attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)